# counting occurrences in all columns

Tags: r, matrix, count, plyr

I have a matrix that looks like this

> mymat

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
9   9   9   9   9   9
1   1   1   6   1   6
1   1   1   6   1   9
1   1   1   6   1   9
1   1   1   6   1   6
```

I want to count occurrences of each number by column, and write a separate matrix such as

```
n1 n6 n9
4  0  1
4  0  1
4  0  1
0  4  1
4  0  1
0  2  3
```

Where each row represents occurrences of the respective column. I managed to count occurrences by column using

```
require(plyr)    
apply(mymat,2,count)
```

But I obtain a list of data frame with occurrences rather that one matrix. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If you have a list of data frames, could you `cbind` them together into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
table(col(mymat), mymat)

#   mymat
#    1 6 9
#  1 4 0 1
#  2 4 0 1
#  3 4 0 1
#  4 0 4 1
#  5 4 0 1
#  6 0 2 3
```

where `col` gives the column index for each element in the matrix, and a count of the element grouped by the column index can be calculated with the `table()` function.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for